# Git doesn't show formatted on my cli but it does for others?

Tags: git

So, I am doing my best to get more used to the command line when using git. Just want to leave the GitHub UI and do it in a more professional manner.

However, I am having a hard time understanding why in most videos/screenhots, I see the following formatting: (Image I can not attach: http://puu.sh/842Qc.png)
First thing, the (master) branch indicator doesn't show up for me, then the tree -git | more command doesn't even work. Does git has it's own cli tool? Like, a separate program to run this git specific commands? I am so confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/git/commands.htm) link might clarify a few things for if you don't quite understand git. Antzi is right though.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however. I do know the commands I need to push pull and commit. My major doubt is why most people have different layout on their command line when working with git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the program that is used. It is called zsh. I found a useful framework for it that provides a simple auto-installer and themes too. https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 1):

They are using the commande line tree utility, not a git-tree command.
See: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is a cli command I just had to install, now I just have to see how they get their branch tag.

Comment: @AlexKvazos What kind of output do you want ? To print branches simply use `git branch` and to display tags use `git tag`

Comment: I finally found the answer. It is a unix shell called Zsh. I am now using that together with the Oh-My-Zsh framework and this themes: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes. I will answer my own question as soon as the 24 hours pass. Thanks!